# java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException

Tags: java

How can i solve this problem. I got following error:

`java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException`

This is coding:

```
 public void run() {

    try {
        SocketChannel socketChannel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(512);
        int i1 = socketChannel.read(buffer);

        if (buffer.limit() == 0 || i1 == -1) {

            Socket s = null;
            try {
                s = socketChannel.socket();
                s.close();
                key.cancel();
            } catch (IOException ie) {
                if (UnitDataServer.isLog) {
                    log.error("Error closing socket " + s + ": " + ie);
                }
            }
        } else {
            buffer.flip();
            if (UnitDataServer.isLog) {
                log.info(" Recvd Message from Unit : " + buffer.array());
            }
            byte byteArray[] = buffer.array();
            log.info("Byte Array length :" + byteArray.length);
            hexString = new StringBuffer();

            for (int i = 0; i < i1 /* byteArray.length */; i++) {
                String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & byteArray[i]);
                if (hex.length() == 1) {
                    // could use a for loop, but we're only dealing with a
                    // single byte
                    hexString.append('0');
                }
                hexString.append(hex);
            }
            hexString.trimToSize();
            log.info("Hex String :" + hexString);

             Communicator.dataReceive(new  DataReceive(
                    socketChannel, hexString.toString(), dst));

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (UnitDataServer.isLog) {
            // log.error(e);
        }
        try {
            socketChannel.socket().close();
            key.cancel();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            if (UnitDataServer.isLog) {
                log.error(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We need some more information on the source code that caused the error and the *exact* stack trace.

Comment: need more info, preferably code examples that shows the exceptions thrown.

Here is the javadoc page, if that helps: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ClosedChannelException.html

Answer (score 13):

You have closed the channel and are still trying to use it.

There are several issues with your code.

First, your test for EOS is faulty. Remove the `limit() == 0` test. That doesn't indicate EOS, it just indicates a zero length read, which can happen in non-blocking mode at any time. It doesn't mean the peer has closed his end of the connection, and it doesn't mean you should close your end.

Second, closing a channel closes the socket as well. You should close the channel only, not the socket.

Third, closing a channel cancels the key. You don't need to follow every close with a cancel.

You may also have failed to check whether a ready key is valid in the select loop before using it, e.g. for reading.

I continue to be amazed, and amused, and bemused, by the claim elsewhere in this thread that 'source code is untrue' under some circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix/secure code that is throwing this exception. *ClosedChannelException* is ...

> ... thrown when an
>   attempt is made to invoke or complete
>   an I/O operation upon channel that is
>   closed, or at least closed to that
>   operation. That this exception is
>   thrown does not necessarily imply that
>   the channel is completely closed. A
>   socket channel whose write half has
>   been shut down, for example, may still
>   be open for reading

(as described in [Java 6 API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ClosedChannelException.html))

But really, you would need to provide us code snipped and stack trace in order to get more detailed help.