# kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer: Reconnect due to socket error: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException

Tags: java, sockets, nio, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am running a simple consumer for kafka such as this:

```
int timeout = 80000;
int bufferSize = 64*1024;
consumer = new SimpleConsumer(host, port,timeout, bufferSize, clientName);
```

This runs fine for a couple of hours but I get an exception
later on 
kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer: Reconnect due to socket error:

> java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException

and consumer stops ... has anyone faced this problem before ?

Comment: There was a reason that your consumer lost connection to the Kafka server. You should check whether your server is alive or not? check the port is still correct(can telnet to broker, zookeeper)?

Comment: hey, any update on it? I do get ClosedChannelException from SimpleConsumer. What is the fix for it?

Comment: @BlueDog see answer below, it might help.

Comment: Can you please paste the rest of the code that uses this consumer? In particular: are you making any call to consumer.close() anywhere in the code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801087/java-nio-channels-closedchannelexception)

Comment: You have to post more information to answer this. Like stack trace and your read logic for Kafka. Possibly you are closing connection for each read from Kafka and trying to read it again without opening the connection again. Again we need to look at the consumer code.

Comment: This is a bug in somebody's code: yours or Kafka's. `ClosedChannelException` means that *your application* closed the channel.It does *not* mean a 'lost connection to the server' @NangSaigon

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different question, but perhaps with the same root cause and solution was [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16867957/983722), the relevant part:

> You have closed the channel and are still trying to use it.
>
> There are several issues with your code.
>
> First, your test for EOS is faulty. Remove the limit() == 0 test. That
>   doesn't indicate EOS, it just indicates a zero length read, which can
>   happen in non-blocking mode at any time. It doesn't mean the peer has
>   closed his end of the connection, and it doesn't mean you should close
>   your end.
>
> Second, closing a channel closes the socket as well. You should close
>   the channel only, not the socket.
>
> Third, closing a channel cancels the key. You don't need to follow
>   every close with a cancel.
>
> You may also have failed to check whether a ready key is valid in the
>   select loop before using it, e.g. for reading.