# Kafka + Spark Streaming: ClosedChannelException

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to run a Spark Streaming job with Kafka.

I send a csv log file via Kafka, so that it publishes messages to my Spark Streaming application.

I use a direct approach in my Spark Streaming application to achieve this.

The data from my log file nicely chugs in at the beginning, but after a while I see the following error message on my Scala IDE.

Environment: I am running Spark locally on all my cores. Zookeeper, Kafka is also being run locally on my system.

ERROR:

```
16/09/05 17:53:28 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 390.0 (TID 390)
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:100)
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.liftedTree1$1(SimpleConsumer.scala:78)
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.kafka$consumer$SimpleConsumer$$sendRequest(SimpleConsumer.scala:68)
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(SimpleConsumer.scala:112)
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:112)
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:112)
    at kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:33)
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1.apply$mcV$sp(SimpleConsumer.scala:111)
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:111)
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:111)
    at kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:33)
```

What happens is this exception is thrown mid-way and sometimes a bunch of log data follows this error message on the console.

I am little confused because this looks like a network error - "Closed Channel Exception" but since I am running all these processes locally, I am wondering if something else might actually be the root cause.

It would be great if I could get some pointers to resolve this issue.

Comment: did the below answer help for you?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: @dirceusemighini see answer from post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35807844/kafka-consumer-simpleconsumer-reconnect-due-to-socket-error-java-nio-channels/43105342#43105342 , it might help.

Comment: @Nietzsche thanks, I think that my problem was something with config, but this environment has been shutdown and I can't test solutions to it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Replace localhost with your machine IP in the kafka producer.properties config(like in metadata.broker.list). Also in /etc/hosts file replace:

127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain

with

x.x.x.x   localhost localhost.localdomain

where x.x.x.x is your machine IP.
See if it helps.

Comment: Hi, 
Thank you for your comments. I tried what you said but unfortunately it is still giving the same error. 

My Kafka is installed in Windows 10 so I was unable to find /etc/hosts on my machine. However, I changed the producer.properties file as indicated. 
metadata.broker.list=xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx