# Freeswitch channel exception

Tags: java, sockets, nio, freeswitch

I use official java client library for esl. I get the following exception

```
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
```

when I try to connect to a socket from Freeswitch after some time of normal work.

Please help me to resolve it.

Comment: you may get help from this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801087/java-nio-channels-closedchannelexception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ClosedChannelException says that you have closed the channel and continued to use it.

following could be possible issue you need to check .

1) Programming error

2) [patch for java org.freeswitch.esl.client library](https://freeswitch.org/jira/browse/ESL-61?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.sy%20stem.issuetabpanels%3Achangehistory-tabpanel)