# WebSocket connection can't reconnect after some time

Tags: java, websocket, jetty

I wrote some logic which represent near 200 websocet connection with exchange at the same time.I use third party api and it based on **org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api**. I have this method which i had to override.

```
try {
            URI uri = new URI(websocketBaseUrl + url);
            SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
            sslContextFactory.setTrustAll(true); 
            WebSocketClient client = new WebSocketClient(sslContextFactory);
            client.setMaxIdleTimeout(0);
            client.start();
            return client.connect(adapter, uri).get();
        } catch (URISyntaxException  e) {
            throw new BinanceApiException("URL Syntax error: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new BinanceApiException("Websocket error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

I added setIdleTimeout to it so that the connection is not lost when i don't recieve information for a long time.
Exchange close connection one time a day but for 2,3 sometimes 4 days it have been reconnected.But finally i get this:

> java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null    at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.onClose(WriteFlusher.java:507)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.onIncompleteFlush(SslConnection.java:527)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint$2.onIncompleteFlush(AbstractEndPoint.java:54)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.write(WriteFlusher.java:331)   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.write(AbstractEndPoint.java:372)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.FrameFlusher$Flusher.flush(FrameFlusher.java:153)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.FrameFlusher$Flusher.process(FrameFlusher.java:217)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.processing(IteratingCallback.java:241)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:224)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.FrameFlusher.enqueue(FrameFlusher.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.outgoingFrame(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:614)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.io.WebSocketClientConnection.outgoingFrame(WebSocketClientConnection.java:72)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.onConnectionStateChange(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:473)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.IOState.notifyStateListeners(IOState.java:184)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.IOState.onReadFailure(IOState.java:498)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.readParse(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:666)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.onFillable(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:511)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:104)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:289)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$3.succeeded(SslConnection.java:149)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:104)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:243)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:679)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:597)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

I find this question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801087/java-nio-channels-closedchannelexception) but i can't see clear answer. Pls help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the connection to stay open if idle, you should configure your client this way:

```
client.setMaxIdleTimeout(Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

Setting maxIdleTimeout to 0 would have the opposite effect: Closing the connection as soon as it becomes idle.

Comment: I'll try it.Thanks.

Comment: Setting the Max IdleTimeout to `Long.MAX_VALUE` is only going to keep Jetty's WebSocketClient from closing the connection.  Other players in the network stack could close the connection on their own idle timeout configuration.  (eg: the jvm network stack, the os network stack, the network itself, the http intermediaries, the remote network stack, the remote network server configuration, the remote websocket endpoint configuration, etc...)